Angel of the Lord in the New Testament?
I'm still confused on how nobody has pointed this out.
"...behold, an angel of the Lord stood next to him, and a light shone in the cell. He struck Peter on the side and woke him, saying, “Get up quickly.” And the chains fell off his hands."
"But motioning to them with his hand to be silent, he described to them how the Lord had brought him out of the prison. And he said, “Tell these things to James and to the brothers.” Then he departed and went to another place."
Also isn't the angel in Revelation described as "standing on both the earth and the sea"? Isn't that sometimes said of other pagan deities?

Yes - but what is your point?

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics SE Steven! When you get a chance, please take the tour to understand how the site works and the guide for new users. Also consider going through the Help Center's  sections on asking and answering questions.

The only question here begins with "Also", implying that you think you've already asked a question. What was that primary question?

Well Steven, maybe I can help you out on this issue. The first thing you need to know is that "THE" angel of the Lord first appears at Genesis 16:7 as the angel of the Lord.
Secondly, "The" angel of the Lord is the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ and I can prove it from  scripture in the Old Testament. I am not going to do it now.
Thirdly, there is only ONE angel of the Lord in scripture, and he never appears in the New Testament as "THE" angel of the Lord. He is mentioned in the New Testament by Stephen at Acts 7.
By now your probably wondering why I'm taking the time to say, "THE" angel of the Lord and why it is "capitalized?" You quoted Acts 12:7 where an angel struck Peter and woke him up.
There is a difference in the function between the word, "an/a" and the word "the." The chief grammatical function of "an" (or a) is to connote a thing not previously noted or recognized, while "the" connotes a thing previously noted or recognized.
At Acts 12:7 this is an ordinary angel who just appears and helps out Peter. At Acts 5:19, "But an angel of the Lord opened the gates etc. Same thing at Acts 8:26, "an angel." Matthew 1:20, 1:24, 2:13 and Matthew 28:2.
You mentioned the book of Revelation and "an/a" angel of the Lord does not appear. However, Jesus appears in the book of Revelation but not as "THE" angel of the Lord. I hope this helps!
If you want to learn about the angel of the Lord start at Genesis 16:7 and read the rest of the chapter taking note of vs10 and vs13. Also read Genesis 17:1-3 and put it together with Genesis 16:10 and the word, "multiply."
Also read Genesis 18, especially Genesis 22 and all of Exodus chapter 3, who's in the burning bush?
